# How to shade a mesh according to UV distortion / mesh size?

Tags: shaders, geometry

I'm trying to create a reasonably-accurate article of clothing for a character. Unfortunately, cloth simulation is... very challenging for this particular case, and while I *am* using some simulation as a guide, I think what I really need to do is manually model the clothing in its 'final' state.

The problem is getting the folds to be the right size.

Because this is clothing, the UV unwrap is theoretically an exact representation of the 'neutral' state of the cloth. (In fact, my reference simulation starts out as a 2D mesh.)

What I want is a way to shade the mesh based on the difference between its UV map and its 3D geometry. What I'm imagining is computing, for U and V independently, the difference of the UV derivative (times some scale factor) and the 3D derivative and mapping that to a color.

To try to describe this better, consider a UV map that is a regular, square grid, and a cylinder whose circumference equals its axial dimension. With appropriate scale factor, the derivative difference would be zero everywhere. If I grab just the top vertices of the cylinder and move them outward along the cylinder's axis, those faces would be stretched relative to one dimension of the UV map. If I grab one 'column' of the cylinder's vertices and move it away from the axis, those faces would be stretched relative to the other dimension of the UV map. If I instead moved them *toward* the axis, they would initially be compressed, but at some point they would have the same size, and the shading would allow me to estimate that point.

Now consider a simple square. If I stretch or shrink it in either direction, the shading would show that. However, if I move one edge to make a rhombus, the shading would indicate that there is no stretching or compression.

Is there any way to do this?

---

**WARNING: Calculus ahead**

In case the above is unclear, and/or to clarify that what I'm trying to do is at least theoretically possible, here's a very technical explanation.

Imagine a three dimensional representation of a garment. In principle, this garment consists of one or more panels of fabric which notionally have two dimensional forms. In fact, due to translation-agnosticism, we can ignore the "or more" and focus on the single-panel case.

Therefore, there exists a transformation of our mesh which is two-dimensional, and for which the mesh's world coordinates are exactly the coordinates expressed in terms of a hypothetical sheet of fabric from which the panel was cut. (Modulo a translation transformation, but since translations don't affect our desired function, we can ignore that.) Now, we need a way to encode these 'fabric-space coordinates' into each of the mesh's vertices. For simplicity's sake, let us say that the 'fabric-space coordinates' are exactly the texture (UV) coordinates, modulo a translation (which is irrelevant) and uniform scale (which can be accounted for with a trivial modification).

In this state, our desired function has a uniform value of $(1, 1)$. Moreover, we can define the function as follows:

- For a point $p$ on the mesh having fabric (texture) coordinates $(u, v)$, let $i$ represent a vector such that the fabric (texture) coordinates of $p + i$ are $(u+t, v)$.
- Let the first value of the function be defined as $lim_{|i| \to 0}\frac{|i|}{t}$.
- Let the second value be similarly determined in terms of $j$, where the fabric (texture) coordinates of $p + j$ are $(u, v+t)$.

For our flattened panel, this produces a uniform value of $(S, S)$, where $S$ is a scaling constant that represents the transformation from fabric coordinates to texture coordinates. (We could additionally account for rotations and non-uniform scaling, but as my use case does not need to do so, let's keep things simple!)

Now, if we take our flattened panel and stretch (or compress) it in the direction of the warp, only one of the function's values will change, and, assuming the transformation is uniform, the new value will remain constant at all points. Similarly, scaling along the weft will affect only the other coordinate. Translations and rotations will have no effect.

More generally, when we now deform the mesh so that it is again three dimensional, the function values (adjusted for $S$) will specify the amount by which the hypothetical fabric has been stretched or compressed along the warp and weft. Visualizing these from the specified function is straight-forward.

It's worth noting that modeling is not the only application for this; materials that change their properties when stretched (e.g. latex becomes more transparent) might also use this.

Comment: I stopped here: "...  a cylinder whose circumference equals its radius". How is that possible?

Comment: @Leander, oops! I meant "height"! Thanks! (Height? Length? Axial dimension; let's go with that, it seems less ambiguous.)